# Custom Object does not fully encode into JSON Object

Tags: actionscript, flex4

I have the following class:

```
public class PartBean extends DatabaseObjectBean{
  [Bindable]
  public var partNumber:String;
  [Bindable]
  public var description:String;

  public var enterpriseIdentifiers:ArrayList;
}
```

Part is already defined as such. 
Part Number = -1
Description = Test
The list is filled with another Object["Name1", "Name2, "Name3"] etc..

In another object I call:

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSONEncoder;
public function blah(){

    JSONEncoder encoder = new JSONEncoder();
    Alert.show(encoder.encode(part);
}
```

I end up with this string: {"description":"Test","partNumber":"-1"}

I am not sure why the array is not being encoded as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer is simply that the encoder needs the items to be bindable in order to see them.

```
[Bindable] 
    public var enterpriseIdentifiers:ArrayList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write your own serialization code for the ArrayList. The JSON encoder provided with ActionScript will only encode native ActionScript objects.

Comment: This is not a JAVA question. This is an Actionscript question and has nothing to do with RMI.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Same problem though.